# Use of sed in perl?

Tags: sed

I want to re-use the code given [here](https://github.com/harvard-itsecurity/qradar-seculert-push/blob/master/seculert_rest_qradar.pl), but I'm stuck in understanding the use of `sed`:

```
print "Sending to QRadar...\n";
# SSH To QRadar's Console and push out file + trigger update
`scp -i $qradar_ssh_key -o UserKnownHostsFile=$qradar_ssh_knownhosts -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root\@$qradar_console:/store/configservices/staging/globalconfig/remotenet.conf .`;
`sed -i -e '/^SECULERT/d' remotenet.conf`;
`cat $seculert_qradar_list >> remotenet.conf`;
`scp -i $qradar_ssh_key -o UserKnownHostsFile=$qradar_ssh_knownhosts -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no remotenet.conf root\@$qradar_console:/store/configservices/staging/globalconfig/remotenet.conf`;
```

I would like to know what `sed` is doing over here.

Comment: What a waste of Perl. That is essentially a shell script executed with the overhead of Perl.

Comment: @casey waste?...

Comment: Yes, it isn't Perl, it's just using the back ticks function to do a bunch of shell commands. For instance you don't need to call sed, perl has the s// function built in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the given line,

```
`sed -i -e '/^SECULERT/d' remotenet.conf`;
```

the `-i` flag means that `sed` is editing `remotenet.conf` in place and `-e '/^SECULERT/d'` deletes all lines beginning with "SECULERT".

Comment: Note that if `sed` prints any output, it will be rendered into the Perl source and used as-is as such. (That's the nature of the backticks.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling is this a down-side? can you explain in simple terms.

Comment: It's essentially trusting whatever comes out of `sed` to be safe. In the case of sed that's likely true, but with other commands it might not be. The backtick operator is dangerous in that way, as it can inject unexpected data into the program. If you just want to execute a given command for some reason, `system()` is less bad unless you actually *need* to capture its output (in which case you should do something with the output; stuff it into a variable or something). Now, `system()` has its drawbacks too, but fewer such than the backtick operator (unless you need the semantics of backtick).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling got it excellent explanation. Very kind:)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, in what way are the backticks used here less safe than system()?  Perl is not executing the output of either.  It's simply throwing it away.  It is not an eval().